# Can I execute “Pathfinder > Crop” from the Pathfinder panel and NOT the “Effects > Pathfinder” menu?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

**TLDR:** I need to run `Pathfinder > Crop` on all art in a file that has a clipping mask applied but can’t seem to get Crop to fire correctly.

**UPDATE:** After HOURS of chipping away at this I came to realize that the Crop option in the main menu (“Effect > Pathfinder > Crop”) does something entirely different than the Crop button in the Pathfinder panel. I’m using `app.executeMenuCommand('Live Pathfinder Crop');` to crop the image, but this apparently fires the menu action. I need to access the crop action from the Pathfinder panel.

---

I have several layers of art that have clipping masks applied. The masks cause several issues in the end product, so I need to:

1. Loop through each layer;
2. Copy the contents to a new layer (optional maybe, but working with the original layers seemed very problematic);
3. Loop through all groups in the layer to find any with `pathItem[0].clipping === true`;
4. Remove the clipping mask;
5. Select and group everything that’s left on the layer;
6. Create a rectangle on top of the art that has the same dimensions and coordinates that the clipping mask had;
7. Select both the group and the rectangle; and
8. Run `Outline Stroke`, `Pathfinder > Crop`, and `Expand` on the selected items.

Here is my script as it stands.

```
#target illustrator

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var tempName = '-temp';

function cropGroups() {
    var layers = doc.layers;
    var layerCount = layers.length;

    // Lock all layers
    for (var i = 0; i < layerCount; i++) {
        layers[i].locked = true;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < layerCount; i++) {
        var layer = layers[i];

        // Create new empty layer
        var layerCopy = layers.add();
        layerCopy.name = layer.name + tempName;

        // Copy all objects from original layer to new layer
        var pageItems = layer.pageItems;
        var pageItemCount = pageItems.length;
        for (var a = pageItemCount - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
            pageItems[a].duplicate(layerCopy, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
        }

        // Loop through the new layer’s groups
        var groups = layerCopy.groupItems;
        var totalGroups = groups.length;
        for (var g = totalGroups - 1; g >= 0; g--) {
            var group = groups[g];

            // Ensure group isn’t empty and has a clipping mask
            if (group.pathItems.length && group.pathItems[0].clipping) {
                var clippingMask = group.pathItems[0];
                var clippingRect = { left: clippingMask.left, top: clippingMask.top, height: clippingMask.height, width: clippingMask.width };
                clippingMask.remove();

                // Time to start the selection dance…
                layerCopy.hasSelectedArtwork = true;

                // Add selected items to a new group
                var selectedItems = doc.selection;
                var cropGroup = layerCopy.groupItems.add(); // Create empty group
                for (var s = 0; s < selectedItems.length; s++) {
                    selectedItems[s].move( cropGroup, ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND ); // Add all selected items to the new group
                }

                doc.selection = null;

                // Create a new rectangle that matches the size of the clipping mask
                var tile = layerCopy.pathItems.rectangle(clippingRect.top, clippingRect.left, clippingRect.width, clippingRect.height);
                var tileColor = new RGBColor;
                tile.fillColor = tileColor;
                tile.move(layerCopy, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);

                // Select all layer art again
                // layerCopy.hasSelectedArtwork = true;
                tile.selected = true;
                cropGroup.selected = true;

                // Live Pathfinder Crop
                app.executeMenuCommand('OffsetPath v22');
                app.executeMenuCommand('Live Pathfinder Crop');
                app.executeMenuCommand('expandStyle');

                doc.selection = null;
            }
        }

        // Return the layer name back to it’s original
        layerCopy.name = layerCopy.name.replace(tempName, '');

        // Remove the original layer
        layer.locked = false;
        layer.remove();
    }
}

cropGroups();
```

It technically works well, but the cropping action isn’t at all what I expect. When I run the script *without* `executeMenuCommand` lines, then run those commands manually in Illustrator everything gets cropped perfectly.

What am I missing here?

**SOLUTION:**

It seems that the “Crop” function from the actual Pathfinder panel isn’t available via ExtendScript, so I ended up making an action that handles only that task and saving it as a file. Then I call it for each Clipping Mask in the document:

```
function cropTiles(cb) {
    // Load the action file relative to the location of this script
    var thisFile = new File($.fileName);
    var basePath = thisFile.path;
    app.unloadAction('action','');
    app.loadAction(new File(basePath + '/actions/action.aia'));

    doc.selection = null;
    app.executeMenuCommand("Clipping Masks menu item");
    var thisClipItem;
    var esc = 50;
    while (doc.selection.length != 0 && esc > 0) {
        esc--;
        thisClipItem = doc.selection[0];
        doc.selection = null;
        thisClipItem.parent.selected = true;

        app.executeMenuCommand('Live Outline Stroke');
        app.doScript('Crop Gallery Tile', 'action');
        app.executeMenuCommand('expandStyle');

        doc.selection = null;
        app.executeMenuCommand("Clipping Masks menu item");
    }
    cb && typeof cb === 'function' && cb();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can execute Pathfinder > Crop via creating Action and running it from code.

- open Action panel and create new Action Set, for example PathfinderSet
- create new empty Action, for example act-crop
- start recording and record one step - applying pathfinder crop to some objects
- open Action context menu and save PathfinderSet to file, for example 'pathfinder-actions.aia'

Run this action from script:

```
  var fAction = new File('pathfinder-actions.aia');
  app.loadAction(fAction); 
  app.doScript("act-crop", "PathfinderSet", false);   
  app.unloadAction("PathfinderSet","");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the only difference between 'Crop' in Pathfinder' panel and 'Crop' in menu 'Effect > Pathfinder' is the later works with grouped or masked objects only. While the former handles ungrouped objects as well.

So, this variant of the script works fine for me:

```
var groups = app.activeDocument.groupItems;

for (var i=0; i<groups.length; i++) {
    try {
        if (groups[i].pathItems[0].clipping) {
            groups[i].selected = true;
            app.executeMenuCommand('OffsetPath v22');
            app.executeMenuCommand("Live Pathfinder Crop");
            app.executeMenuCommand("expandStyle");
            app.selection = null;
        }
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

It just iterates through all groups, tries to pick first path and, if the path is a clip mask, executes the commands. I see no difference on my test files. Am I missing something?