# Select items on the page with the same appearance extendscript

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Is it possible to use extendscript to select items on the page with the same appearance, something like this?  I'm not sure if the command is available or what the syntax is. I have a line selected and would like to select all other lines on the artboard that are the same, something like

```
app.executeMenuCommand('select-same-appearance');
```

An I'm struggling to find any documentation. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the same"? Do they have the same color, size and so on? Do they also need to have the same position? What do you mean by line? A line from A to B or a line of text?

Comment: You may need to achieve this by creating an _Action_, then recording _`Select`_ > _`Same`_ > _`Appearance`_ from the _Menu Bar,_ and running it from your code. In a similar way to what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912799/can-i-execute-pathfinder-crop-from-the-pathfinder-panel-and-not-the-effects#answer-42922124).

Comment: Sorry for being so vague.  I have a series of paths on an illustrator page in what for the sake of this should be considered random positions.  The lines have various colours, weights and dashed strokes. I currently select one path then pull down from the 'select' menu to Same the across to Appearance and hey presto all the lines with the same stroke colour, line weight and dashed attributes are selected. I would like to incorporate this into a script that will perform other actions on the lines

Comment: Thanks, RobC, but I was hoping to keep this within the script. I'm guessing I'm going to have to loop through each item on the page and compare it to the one selected. Then push this to an array of objects for selection

Comment: @BobHaslett - Yes, comparing the properties of each page item with that of the properties of the current selection, (during each turn of the loop), does seem like a viable solution. The answer I previously liked too does sort of _" keep [it] within the script"_, however I guess it's the dependency of the additional `.aia` file that you're wanting to avoid. It's worth noting that the content of an `.aia` file is text, so you could _perhaps_ try generating/saving the `.aia` file to the systems temp folder via your script, then loading/running the action as per the answer I linked to previously.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.executeMenuCommand('Find Appearance menu item');
```

You can use this [map](https://github.com/ten-A/AiMenuObject) of Illustrator's treasures.