# Run Illustrator extension through a script

Tags: scripting, adobe-illustrator

I have been using .jsx scripts to automate some tasks in Illustrator, but I haven’t figured out how to execute actions from extensions through a script. I would for example like to push from Illustrator to After Effects using the Overlord extension and export a lottie file by using the Bodymovin extension.
Is this possible? How would I get the list of possible actions for an extension inside a .jsx script?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know we have only two options in Illustrator:

1. To execute menu items this way:

```
app.executeMenuCommand("expandStyle");
```

More or less full list of menu commands is here: https://github.com/ten-A/AiMenuObject

2. To record actions and execute them this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42922124/14265469

So, if your extension doesn't work via menus or actions you can't execute it from script.

Sometimes something can be done with external apps like AutoHotkey (Windows) that able to move and click mouse cursor and press keyboard buttons.